# d3.layout.pack stacks circles when sort is ascending

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js, circle-pack

I have a dataset such that when sorted in ascending order the circles end up 'stacked' but appear properly distributed when using null or descending sort order.

[image: ascending]

[image: descending]

[image: null]

Complete example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXLHx/3/.

Anyone have a suggestion?

```
    sortItems = function(a,b) {
        var str,result;
        switch(sortOrder%3){
            case 0:
                str = 'ascending';
                result = a.size - b.size;
                break;
            case 1:
                str = 'descending';
                result = b.size - a.size;
                break;
            default:
                str = 'null';
                result = null;
        }
        document.getElementById("sortLbl").innerHTML = str;
        return result;
    };

    pack = d3.layout.pack().sort(sortItems);
```

Some additional info:

I found that if I remove at least two of the blocks entries that have the value 0 (didn't matter which two but it had to be two) the layout is fine. http://jsfiddle.net/SXLHx/4/

Also, applying a filter to not append circles with 0 value like so:

```
    // Create circles
    node.append("circle")
        .filter(function(d){return d.size > 0;})
        .attr("r",function(d){return d.r;});
```

does not correct the layout issue. Maybe I'm filtering incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: We need to investigate further. Ascending order is working in this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/npUSyrG8sHsQrqUPw7Y7?p=preview), which is based on this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a couple of mistakes in the portion of code that is supposed to set new order and update the layout. It should look like this: (it is even simpler than what is currently in the code)

```
pack
  .sort(sortItems)
  .nodes({blocks:data});

node
  .attr("transform",function(d){
      return "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")";
  })
  .selectAll("circle")
  .attr("r",function(d){return d.r;});
```

I solved zero values with this line in pack initialization:

```
.value(function(d){return Math.max(0.01, d.size);});
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZZ8d/).

Here is video of execution:

[image]

(note that after third button-press, circles do not return to original order, but this is due to other reasons that don't have direct connection to original problem (which is about ascending/descending order in circle pack)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will work for my use case. Thanks for the code corrections to my ordering, updating and filtering. I still think there is something wrong with d3 though since without the filtering part the corrupt layout is dependent on the presence of at least three 0 values in the data. If I remove two of the 0 vals the layout is fine.

Comment: How can I pack circles with moving effect just like in force layout circle pack. ??